# Programmatically write an associative array of functions

Tags: php, key, associative-array

I have a lot of functions stored in an associative array like this :

```
$arr['my-title'] = function(){process(146,'My Title');};
$arr['un-cafe-chaud'] = function(){process(857,'Un café chaud');};
$arr['vpn'] = function(){process(932,'VPN');};
$arr['another-example'] = function(){process(464,'Another example');};
```

Currently I have to encode manually each key.

As the key name is function of the Title, I'd like to automate it.

```
 function assign_keys($title,$id){
$u=str_replace(array(' ','é'),array('-','e'),strtolower($title));
$arr[$u] = function(){process($id,$title);};
}
```

But it doesn't work, as process function can't get `$id` and `$title` value.

Any help on how I could handle this would be highly appreciated ! Thank you.

Comment: what does `process` do exactly ? and how are you using this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should pass `$arr` as argument to the function in order to be able to mutate it. Second, you should use `use` to make those two variables available in the anonymous function, like this:

```
function assign_keys($title,$id, &$arr){
    $u=str_replace(array(' ','é'),array('-','e'),strtolower($title));
    $arr[$u] = function() use ($id, $title){process($id,$title);};
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$arr = [];

assign_keys('Some title', 123, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

This should print:

```
array(1) {
  ["some-title"]=>
  object(Closure)#1 (1) {
    ["static"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(123)
      ["title"]=>
      string(10) "Some title"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you 1 billion times ! This is exactly what I needed, wasn't aware of the `use` keyword, which does the trick ! Very sorry I have not enough reputation to upvote you.

Comment: @Xavier glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a reference `&` to get the array outside of the function and `use` to get the variables into the closure:

```
function assign_keys($title, $id, &$arr){
    $u = str_replace(array(' ','é'), array('-','e'), strtolower($title));
    $arr[$u] = function() use($title, $id) { process($id, $title); };
}

assign_keys('My Title', 146, $arr);
```